# is it OK to use ruby's implicit return value from []=

Tags: ruby

I am wandering if it is OK to use ruby's implicit return value when using `[]=` method

`[]=` uses `rb_hash_aset` and it is returning `val` - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D

here is a little code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
require 'benchmark'
CACHE = {}
def uncached_method(key)
    warn "uncached"
    rand(100)
end
def cached(key)
  CACHE[key] || (CACHE[key] = uncached_method(key))
end
def longer_cached(key)
  return CACHE[key] if CACHE[key]
  CACHE[key] = uncached_method(key)
  CACHE[key]
end

Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
    y = rand(10000)
    cached(y)
    x.report("shorter:") { 10000000.times do cached(y) end }
    x.report("longer:") { 10000000.times do longer_cached(y) end }
end
```

of course `longer_cached` is slower because it does two hash lookups to return cached value, but when you read it line by line it makes more sense then the `cached` method.

I think using implicit returns is one of the things that makes ruby awesome, but I have always questioned their use when setting values.

So my question is: would you use implicit return from `(hash[key] = val)`?

Comment: Why doesn't using `||` make sense? Isn't it the same as in natural language? For example, in English, "(give me) `CACHE[key]`, or else assign it, (then give it to me)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because nobody mentioned it so far: you are not relying on the return value of `Hash#[]=`. That return value gets ignored anyway:

```
class ReturnFortyTwo
  def []=(*)
    return 42
  end
end

r = ReturnFortyTwo.new

r[23] = 'This is the value that is going to be returned, not 42'
# => 'This is the value that is going to be returned, not 42'
```

In Ruby, assignment expressions *always* evaluate to the value that is being assigned. No exception. That is guaranteed by the Language Specification. So, I don't see anything wrong with relying on that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `||=` operator in this case.

```
CACHE[key] ||= uncached_method(key)
```

This is a very common idiom.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, shorter one is preferrable. Ussually `=` used in a subexpression is frowned upon, but here it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it as simple and clean as possible (it's faster, too):

```
def cached(key)
  value = CACHE[key]
  unless value
    value = uncached_method(key)
    CACHE[key] = value
  end
  value
end
```